# How to render a div next to my mouse even after scroll down

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, css-position

Basically I want to render a div next to where I click.
I have done that works perfectly but my problem is when I scroll down its not following and render relevant to the page and not the screen.
Any work around my code if this so far:

```
const [position, setPosition] = useState([0,0])

const renderGuess = (event) =>{ 
  if(guessed){
    setPosition([0,0]);
    setGuessed(false);
  }else{
    setPosition([event.clientX, event.clientY]);
    setGuessed(true);
  }
}

function Guess (position){
    const {location} = position
    console.log(location)

    return(
        <div id="guess-div" style={{top: `${location[1]}px`, left: `${location[0]}px`}}>
```

Note: I'm using react the render works fine only problem is when I scroll down it renders for example 150px from the top of the page not 150px from the screen.
I have tried 150 / 10, with vh and vw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` will get the viewport coordinates, not the document coordinates as you want.

You can replace the

```js
setPosition([event.clientX, event.clientY]);
```

by

```js
setPosition([event.pageX, event.pageY]);
```

to get the coordinates relative to the entire document instead.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX